# Substitute variable into match

Tags: regular-expression, variables

This highlights the parts of the lines that are over 80 columns long:

```
augroup over_length
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkgrey
    autocmd BufEnter * match OverLength /\%80v.*/
augroup END
```

However, I would like to modify it to use `&textwidth`. Using `/\%.&textwidth.v.*/` doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to substitute the value into the regular expression?

Comment: My want to consider using `set colorcolumn=80`. See `:h 'cc'`

Comment: @PeterRincker I find `colorcolumn` too distracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use execute and put it in a string:

```
execute 'match OverLength /\%'. &textwidth .'v.*/'
```